# VBA, IF and Vlookup statement

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following formula,

```
=IF(valumeasure3!E2="Buy Notional Amount",VLOOKUP(C2,valumeasure3!C:U, COLUMNS(C:U),FALSE),0)
```

trying to automate this formula in vba, I get a syntax error. Vlookup formulas work fine, but as soon as I do the IF statement i get syntax error. I believe it is to do with the `=`

```
Range("R2").Select
        ActiveCell = "=IF(valumeasure3!E2="Buy Notional Amount",VLOOKUP(C2,valumeasure3!C:U, COLUMNS(C:U),FALSE),0)"   ''buy currency amt
        Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("R2:R4182")
```

Comment: `"Buy Notional Amount"` needs to be `""Buy Notional Amount""`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VBA, when you use quotation marks you are setting a boundary to a string. You should use double quotes.

```
Range("R2").Select
    ActiveCell = "=IF(valumeasure3!E2=""Buy Notional Amount"",VLOOKUP(C2,valumeasure3!C:U, COLUMNS(C:U),FALSE),0)"    ''buy currency amt
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("R2:R4182")
```

However, a suggestion is that I would recommend that you not use `.Select` and `ActiveCell` whenever possible.

```
Dim Rng as Range
Set Rng = Range("R2")
Rng.Value = ....
```

Comment: instead of Activecell, seletion, and select I can just use rng right?

Comment: @excelguy Yes that should work for you.You wouldn't need the `Range("R2").Select` line at all.

Comment: @excelguy take a look at this question about avoiding using Select and ActiveCell https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba